# Can a GAE Spring DispatcherServlet save different Data Objects to the same PersistenceManagerFactory?

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, maven, spring-mvc, jdo

I am working on a Spring DispatcherServlet deployed to Google App-Engine that uses a JDO PersistenceManagerFactory for storage.

I am developing in Eclipse using a combination of the eclipse Maven Plugin and the Maven appengine Plugin. (I do not have the Google App Engine Plugin for Eclipse installed because I was unsuccessful getting that setup to work.)

I’ve used this project as a basis for my own:
https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-14/tree/master/examples/12-VideoSvcAppEngineJDO
Copyright 2014, Jules White

I’ll admit that although I am an experienced C++ developer I have little to no previous experience with any of the technologies/tools that I’m attempting to use here. I’ve exhausted myself trying to figure this out and I can’t say for sure where in the process the mistakes are. I have a partially working project and will be happy to post any additional code that you feel is helpful.

## Topic 1:

Let me start with a fundamental presumption of my design. I am of the understanding that one PersistenceManagerFactory should be able to handle many different JDO Classes. In my example I have a Caregiver Object and a Patient Object each marked up with DataNucleus Annotation.

### Caregiver.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Caregiver {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private String firstName;

    @Persistent
    private String lastName;

    @Persistent
    private String phone;

    @Persistent
    private String email;

    @Persistent
    public ArrayList<Long> patients;

    public Caregiver() {
        patients = new ArrayList<Long>();
    }
    ...
```

### Patient.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Patient {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long sysId;

    @Persistent
    private Long caregiverId;

    @Persistent
    private String firstName;

    @Persistent
    private String lastName;

    @Persistent
    private String recordNum;

    @Persistent
    private String dob;

    @Persistent
    private ArrayList<Long> checkIns;

    @Persistent
    private ArrayList<Long> meds;

    public Patient() {
        checkIns = new ArrayList<Long>();
        meds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    }
    ...
```

I access the PersistenceManagerFactory through and adaptation of the interface provided in Dr. Whites Code. My adaptation is supposed to extent the PMF to multiple data types.

### JDOCrudRepository.java

```
....
public Object save(Object entity) {
    return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().makePersistent(entity);
}
....
public Iterable<Object> findAll(Class<?> type) {
    Query query = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().newQuery(type);
    Object rslt = query.execute();
    return (Collection<Object>) rslt;
}
....
```

### PMF.java

```
/*
 * @author jules
 * 
 */
public final class PMF {
     private final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper
                .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

     public PMF() {
     }

     public PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
          return pmfInstance;
     }
}
```

I am able to build and test the project using the command “mvn appengine:dev_server”
Using my spring dispatcherServlet I have wired functions to add and retrieve Caregiver Objects from the PersistenceManagerFactory.

### CaregiverService.java

```
....
// GET ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TODO: Dangerous in production
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = CaregiverSvcApi.CAREGIVER_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Collection<Caregiver> getCaregiverList() {
    ArrayList<Object> objList = Lists.newArrayList(repo
            .findAll(Caregiver.class));

    ArrayList<Caregiver> cg = new ArrayList<Caregiver>();
    for (Object object : objList) {
        cg.add(object != null ? (Caregiver) object : null);
    }

    return cg;
}
...
// POST ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = CaregiverSvcApi.CAREGIVER_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Caregiver postCaregiver(@RequestBody Caregiver cg) {
    cg.setIdNull();
    Caregiver newCg = (Caregiver) repo.save(cg);
    return newCg;
}
...
```

These work fine as demonstrated by the results fetched from my dev server

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/caregiver
[{"id":5676073085829120,"firstName":"Cg","lastName":"One","phone":"1234567","email":"1@x.com","patients":[]},
{"id":5682617542246400,"firstName":"z","lastName":"z","phone":"123","email":"z@z.com","patients":[]},
{"id":5715999101812736,"firstName":"c","lastName":"s","phone":"123","email":"c@s.com","patients":[]}]
```

## To the meat of the problem…

If I apply the same methodology to my Patient Object

### CaregiverSvc.java

```
...
// GET ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = CaregiverSvcApi.PATIENT_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Collection<Patient> getPatientList() {
    ArrayList<Object> objList = Lists.newArrayList(repo
            .findAll(Patient.class));

    ArrayList<Patient> p = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    for (Object object : objList) {
        p.add(object != null ? (Patient) object : null);
    }

    return p;
}
...
// POST ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = CaregiverSvcApi.PATIENT_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Patient postPatient(@Body Patient p) {
    p.setIdNull();
    Patient newP = (Patient) repo.save(p);
    return newP;
}
...
```

Now when I post or get Patient Objects my results are always null.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/patient
[{"id":5113123132407808,"caregiverId":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"recordNum":null,"dob":null,"checkIns":[],"meds":[]},
{"id":5697423099822080,"caregiverId":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"recordNum":null,"dob":null,"checkIns":[],"meds":[]}]
```

All of my patient objects are stored as null values as if my PersistenceManagerFactory does not know how to interpret the Patient Object.

## Topic 2:

If I indeed am using a PersistenceManagerFactory appropriately. Is there anything more I need to do to get the PersistenceManagerFactory to properly handle the Patient Object?
Your time is greatly appreciated.

Comment: and what state are the objects in when you return them? HOLLOW ? transient? The log would tell you that. The database would tell you what was actually persisted (as would the log)

Comment: I get what appears to be a Patient Object with a valid key and null members returned from my save function. The app engine admin panel reports the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Body Annotation is used in Retrofit.. Your Service should use @RequestBody Annotation to get the Data Object.. That's why server never stored anything and thus returns Null...

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much for putting me back on track.